# How to add dotnet code format bot to GitLab?

Tags: .net, gitlab

How to automatically run the code format bot with `dotnet format` command, and create a new merge request when any code be modified.

As we know, we can add the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to run the command in GitLab Runner. Any tools can help us to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The open source tool: [dotnetCampus.GitLabCodeFormatBot](https://github.com/dotnet-campus/dotnetcampus.DotNETBuildSDK)

Add the code to `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```yaml
stages:
  - build

FormatCode:
  # Format rules by .editorconfig file
  stage: build
  script:
    - "dotnet tool update -g dotnetCampus.GitLabCodeFormatBot"
    - "AutomateFormatCodeAndCreateGitLabMergeRequest -Token Your_GitLab_Token"
  only:
    - dev
```